# "Access denied" on public shares belong to an external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, network-shares

I have two drives, `C:` and `D:`. `C:` is the main hard drive, and `D:` is my external hard drive that is connected via USB.

On my computer, I'm able to access both `\\localhost\c$` and `\\localhost\d$` fine. However, when connecting from other devices, `\\\10.0.0.8\c$` is a valid folder (as in allows me in with my correct credentials) while `\\10.0.0.8\d$` replies with "Access Denied" no matter if a password was entered or not..

According to many reports, this seems to be a bug caused by a computer policy which enables the auditing object access over network, however - The setting in question is disabled; it's never been turned on at all. Point is, I can't turn it off because it is *already* off.

Others have suggested to rather use admin shares, use a regular share to any folder that isn't the root. Unfortunately, the "Access Deined" error still stands when trying to access a shared directory that was on the external drive `D:`. Even with full permissions, anything on `D:` would yield an "Access Denied" while anything `C:` would function just fine.

Symbolic links (remapping a `C:` folder to be simply an alias of said folder in `D:`) does not seem to work at all.

What could be causing this problem, and how would I allow access to my external drive? Could a different policy or some hidden Registry setting be causing it?

---

It's worth noting that I tried accessing with both another Windows 10 PC, and through my Android phone.

---

**Update:** So upon further investigation, the "Access Denied" message appears whenever:

- The specified path does not exist, or:
- An error occurred while accessing said directory, or:
- The request was received successfully, but the response wasn't returned in full (ie. a mid-response disconnect), or:
- The specified path exists, but you do not have permission to view it.

The equivalent of:

[image]

*For the example above, it's the first point. A blank endlessly loading window appears for the third point.*

The "Forbidden" message means that:

- The specified path exists, and you do not have permission to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In the discussion below, assure that you are using an administrator login
for the actions below and for the access over the network.

Try to set [LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942817/how-to-change-the-remote-uac-localaccounttokenfilterpolicy-registry-se):

> The LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy setting affects how administrator credentials are applied to remotely administer the computer.

This command, run as Administrator, will set this registry item:

```
cmd /c reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

If this does not help, try to disable UAC Admin Approval mode:

- Open the Local Security Policy application
- Navigate to *Local Policies > Security Options*
- Set to Disabled the policy
  *User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode*.

The "Access Denied" message should now disappear if you try to access
the D$ Administrative Share with a local account in the administrators group.

Comment: Nope. That's not it. It's already set to `1`. Nice try. A setting of `0` returns a definite "Forbidden". Whereas `1` returns a vague "Access Denied".

Comment: Added another setting.

Comment: Nice try again, still no.

Comment: You might need to disable UAC totally. Even if this will make it work, I would counsel to create your own share in parallel to D$, over which you will have full control, rather than disabling UAC.